# Getting unwanted or unknow data at the end of each data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a text file ,I need to get data from text file and insert into MySQL my code is:

```
    $data = file_get_contents("words.txt");
    $convert = explode("\n", $data);
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","pwd") or die('couldnot connect to database'.mysql_error()); 
for ($i=0;$i<count($convert);$i++)
 {

    mysql_select_db("DB",$con);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Table  VALUES ('".$convert[0]."')";
 }
```

This code inserted data perfectly into database. But an unusual string is inserting at the end of each word. How can I remove that. Thanks in advance. My output looks like.

[image]

After each word a string which looks like zero is adding when I get this data to a form text box this unusual string is acting as enterby which cursor is going to next line in textbox

Comment: What is the encoding on your mysql table?

Comment: Just a hint, not related to your question: You do not need to connect to the DB before every single query. Place the connect and select_db statement above the `for` statement.

Comment: You're injecting code directly into your query. This is not advised. See: http://bit.ly/phpmsql

Comment: Please, don't use mysql_* functions in new code. They are no longer maintained https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation and are officially deprecated

Comment: its utf default collacation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This char could be "\r", try:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Table  VALUES ('".trim($convert[0])."')";
```

Comment: same result i am getting

Comment: Thank you very much it worked very well. Actually i have done mistake before commenting to your question so only i got same result even after i use your suggestion